# Jlabel setText cuando i de bucle for =5

Tags: java-swing

Pretendo que en un label se muestre un texto en intermitente, pero nada me funciona.

Por lo que  probé algo mas fácil: un botón que inicie una cuenta de 0 a 10 con un `for` cuando `i` sea `5` muestra el texto en el label.

Pero es que ni eso funciona. Muestra el texto cuando `i` llega a su final que es `9`. En el debug si entra en el `if i ==5` pero no muestra el texto en el label hasta que acabe el `for`.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class pruebaText {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel lblText;
    int cont = 0;
    private JLabel lblText5;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    pruebaText window = new pruebaText();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public pruebaText() {
        initialize();

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {     
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        lblText = new JLabel("");
        lblText.setBounds(89, 66, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblText);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{
                    while (cont<10) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        cont++;
                        System.out.println(cont);
                        if (cont==5) {
                            lblText.setText("hola");
                        }
                    }

                }catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.out.println(e1);
                }
            }

        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(89, 197, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        lblText5 = new JLabel("");
        lblText5.setBounds(341, 38, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblText5);               
    }
}
```

Este es el metodo real que estoy intentando que funcione  en un boton

```
public static void mostarTexto() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
             //Para ver la evulocion de i en Console de eclipe
            System.out.println(i);

            if (i / 2 == 0) {
                lblTexto.setText("hola");
            } else {
                lblTexto.setText(" ");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Según el `if(i / 2 == 0)` ahí no debería de entrar mas que cuando `i=0` (si no da error), creo que lo que buscabas hacer es (`if(i%2==0)` osease, no buscar el resultado de una división, sino que usarías el "resto"

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que buscas es modificar la interfaz en un loop, y ver los cambios a medida que se ejecuta dicho loop. Entonces el codigo no tiene que estar en el mismo *handler* ya que se ejecutara todo primero y luego se actualizará la interfaz de usuario.

Para lograr lo que quieres puedes iniciar un nuevo *thread* que se encargue de iterar el estado de visibilidad del texto, y en cada iteracion que invoque el cambio de texto en el [*event dispatch thread*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Por ejemplo:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                boolean b = true;
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    b = !b;
                    final boolean mostrar = b;
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if(mostrar) {
                                lblText.setText("Hola");
                            } else {
                                lblText.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

Notar que si lo dejas como *handler* de un boton, se creara un nuevo *thread* cada vez que se utilice.